# Add a colored Ellipse to MenuItem

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, menuitem, bitmapimage

I would like to add an `Ellipse` to some `MenuItems` of my `ContextMenu`.

Sadly I could not get this to work [**Nothing is displayed**].

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas() { Height = 16, Width = 16 };
canvas.Children.Add(new System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse()
{
    Height = 16,
    Width = 16,
    Fill = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Red)
});
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.RenderTargetBitmap((int)canvas.Width, (int)canvas.Height, 96, 96, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Default);

bmp.Render(canvas);
MenuItem tmp = new MenuItem();
tmp.Header = "Away";
tmp.Icon = new System.Windows.Controls.Image()
{
     Source = bmp
};

AddContextMenuEntry(tmp);
```

What am I missing or what is wrong here ?

**Expected result would be sth. like this:**

[image]

Comment: How does *"could not get this to work"* looks like? You are missing [encoder](https://wpftutorial.net/BitmapFromVisual.html) though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No image required: `Icon` is `object`. It can be any content: Any visual element, any value, any instance of any class. If it's a viewmodel it'll need an implicit DataTemplate. But a red circle is a snap.

```
MenuItem tmp = new MenuItem();
tmp.Header = "Away";

tmp.Icon = new System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse()
{
    Height = 16,
    Width = 16,
    Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red
};
```

If you want something more complicated, you could have given it the `Canvas` instead, with the `Ellipse` and other child elements.